# (N)Asm: memset not working correctly

Tags: assembly, nasm, memset

I am assembler newbie from yesterday, so I decided to write simple (as I hoped) functions - memcpy and memset.

Memcpy is working well, but memset not, only sometimes. There must be small mistake, but I can't find it.

**memset**:

```
; NASM syntax


%include 'types.asm'


SEGMENT .CODE
section .text

global  trn_memset
global _trn_memset


; ==========================================================
; memset
; void trn_memset(void* dest, char val, unsigned plong sz)
_trn_memset:
trn_memset:
    %ifdef TRN_64BIT
        getarg tax, 1
        getarg tcx, 2
        getarg tbx, 3
    %else
        mov tax, [tsp + ((2 * sizeof_LONG) + sizeof_INT)]    ; size
        mov tcx, [tsp + (     sizeof_LONG  + sizeof_INT)]    ; tcx = char
        mov tbx, [tsp + (     sizeof_LONG              )]    ; tbx = destination
    %endif

    ; dest = [tsp + (1 * sizeof_LONG)]
    ; src = [tsp + (2 * sizeof_LONG)]
    ; sz = [tsp + (3 * sizeof_LONG)]
    mov tdx, 0                         ; remainder
    mov tcx, 8                         ; tax / tcx
    mov tax, [tsp + (3 * sizeof_LONG)]     ; size
    div tcx
    ;
    mov tbx, [tsp + (1 * sizeof_LONG)]     ; tbx = destination
    mov tcx, [tsp + (2 * sizeof_LONG)]     ; tcx = val
    push tax                           ; save it to stack, we will use al
    mov al, cl
    ; create 32bit int from 8bit value
    ; ((((((val << 8) | val) << 8) | val) << 8) | val)
    mov cl, al
    shl tcx, 8
    mov cl, al
    shl tcx, 8
    mov cl, al
    shl tcx, 8
    mov cl, al
  .cmp_remainder:
    ;cmp tdx, 0
    or tdx, tdx
    jz .aftercmp_remainder
    dec tdx
    mov [tbx], cl
    inc tbx
    jmp .cmp_remainder
  .aftercmp_remainder:
    pop tdx                            ; restore result from stack to tdx
                                       ; because now value in tdx is useless
  .cmp_result:
    ;cmp tdx, 0
    or tdx, tdx
    jz .aftercmp_result
    dec tdx
    ; 2x 32bit set
    mov [tbx], ecx
    add tbx, 4
    ;
    mov [tbx], ecx
    add tbx, 4
    ;
    jmp .cmp_result
  .aftercmp_result:
    mov tax, [tsp + (1 * sizeof_LONG)]     ; tax = destination
    ret
```

**types.asm**:

```
%ifdef WINDOWS
    %define TRN_WIN
%else
    ; TODO make it better
    %define TRN_NIX
%endif


; C Variable types
%ifdef TRN_64BIT
    %define CHAR BYTE
    %define SHORT WORD
    %define INT DWORD
    %define LONG QWORD
    %define LLONG QWORD

    %define DCHAR db
    %define DSHORT dw
    %define DINT dd
    %define DLONG dq
    %define DLLONG dq

    %define sizeof_CHAR 1
    %define sizeof_SHORT 2
    %define sizeof_INT 4
    %define sizeof_LONG 8
    %define sizeof_LLONG 8

    %define sizeof_DCHAR 1
    %define sizeof_DSHORT 2
    %define sizeof_DINT 4
    %define sizeof_DLONG 8
    %define sizeof_DLLONG 8
%else
    %define CHAR BYTE
    %define SHORT WORD
    %define INT DWORD
    %define LONG DWORD
    %define LLONG QWORD

    %define DCHAR db
    %define DSHORT dw
    %define DINT dd
    %define DLONG dd
    %define DLLONG dq

    %define sizeof_CHAR 1
    %define sizeof_SHORT 2
    %define sizeof_INT 4
    %define sizeof_LONG 4
    %define sizeof_LLONG 8

    %define sizeof_DCHAR 1
    %define sizeof_DSHORT 2
    %define sizeof_DINT 4
    %define sizeof_DLONG 4
    %define sizeof_DLLONG 8
%endif


; Registers
%ifdef TRN_64BIT
    %define tax rax
    %define tbx rbx
    %define tcx rcx
    %define tdx rdx
    %define tsp rsp
%else
    %define tax eax
    %define tbx ebx
    %define tcx ecx
    %define tdx edx
    %define tsp esp
%endif


; Getting arguments
; - 64bit nix: rdi, rsi, rdx, rcx, r8, r9
; - 64bit win: RCX, RDX, R8, R9
; getarg(out, arg_index)
; - out can be memory or register
; - arg_index is starting from 1
; - bytes_sz - 1,2,4 or 8 bytes

%ifdef TRN_64BIT
    %ifdef TRN_WIN
        %macro getarg 2
            %if %2 = 1
                mov %1, rcx
            %elif %2 = 2
                mov %1, rdx
            %elif %2 = 3
                mov %1, r8
            %elif %2 = 4
                mov %1, r9
            %elif %2 > 4
                mov %1, [tsp + ((%2 - 4) * 8)]
            %endif
        %endmacro
    %else
        %macro getarg 2
            %if %2 = 1
                mov %1, rdi
            %elif %2 = 2
                mov %1, rsi
            %elif %2 = 3
                mov %1, rdx
            %elif %2 = 4
                mov %1, rcx
            %elif %2 = 5
                mov %1, r8
            %elif %2 = 6
                mov %1, r9
            %elif %2 > 6
                mov %1, [tsp + ((%2 - 6) * 8)]
            %endif
        %endmacro
    %endif
%endif



; Custom commands
%macro pushsz 1
    sub tsp, %1
%endmacro

%macro popsz 1
    add tsp, %1
%endmacro


%macro pushreg 0
    push LONG tdx
    push LONG tcx
    push LONG tbx
    push LONG tax
%endmacro

%macro popreg 0
    pop LONG tax
    pop LONG tbx
    pop LONG tcx
    pop LONG tdx
%endmacro

%macro print 1
    push LONG %1
    call printf
    pop LONG eax
%endmacro
```

**EDIT**

Now, I really don't know what I am doing wrong. Have I got any mistake there? 32bit

```
_trn_memset:
trn_memset:
    mov eax, DWORD [esp + 12]     ; size
    mov ecx, DWORD [esp + 8]      ; tcx = val
    mov ebx, DWORD [esp + 4]      ; tbx = destination

  .memset_loop:
    or eax, eax
    jz .aftermemset_loop
    mov [ebx], BYTE cl
    dec eax
    inc ebx
  .aftermemset_loop:
    mov eax, DWORD [esp + 4]            ; Return destionation
    ret
```

When I compiled kernel & test program with C's memset and assembly written memcpy, it worked, but when I include assembly memset version, there is bad formatting when printing.

Comment: Did you try narrowing the problem down with a debugger? Also, if you have working C versions, you can create assembly versions by having the compiler output assembly then tweaking the results for friendly labeling and efficiency.

Comment: debugger? I don't know how, I am compiling via terminal. But see update

Comment: You have a lot of code there. You need to narrow the problem down somehow. If you don't have or know how to use a debugger, there are other techniques, such as inserting bits of code to display intermediate register values to see if they make sense.

Comment: Did you try just focusing on one platform first, without all the macros, to get that working? That's probably where I'd start.

Comment: I am compiling it to elf32 (+ together with kernel, that is i386), so except the first `%ifdef` and types there are no more macros. Thanks for tip, I am going to try it with plain asm and set every byte.

Comment: Just curious about your memcpy implementation. Does it handle overlapping memory blocks. For example, if you want to copy 100 bytes from address 0x2000 to 0x2001 (i.e. shift a memory block to the right one place), will it work? A naive implementation will end up putting the value from 0x2000 into every position. A correct implementation will not do that.

Comment: Yes, I have got memcpy instead of memmove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code was allright, except that at the beginning all used registers (except first eax/rax) must be `push`ed to stack, and before returning they must be `pop`ed back.

So, the the simplest possible memset for 32bit look like:

```
_trn_memset:
trn_memset:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    add ebp, 4 ; We pushed one register to stack, count it
    push ebx ; Save used registers
    push ecx
    mov eax, DWORD [ebp + 12]     ; size
    mov ecx, DWORD [ebp + 8]      ; tcx = val
    mov ebx, DWORD [ebp + 4]      ; tbx = destination

  .memset_loop:
    or eax, eax ; Fast compare to 0
    jz .aftermemset_loop
    mov [ebx], BYTE cl
    dec eax
    inc ebx
  .aftermemset_loop:
    mov eax, DWORD [ebp + 4]            ; Return destionation
    pop ecx ; Restore used registers
    pop ebx
    pop ebp
    ret
```